console.log() shows different result
I thought below two statement will show same result:
console.log(clickedEvent.target)
console.log(`Clicked Element:${clickedEvent.target}`)

But the result is:
<div>Account</div>
[object HTMLDivElement]

Did I miss something?

your second line implicitly calls toString() on the object. And what you are seeing is the result of that toString call ...

In the first log the browser outputs the outerHTML of the element - note that this is browser dependent and may not always be the case. In the second log the target gets coerced to a string (due to the template literal) using toString(), which outputs [object...]

Because you are trying to convert a DOM object to a string.

solution

// ✅
console.log(`Clicked Element: `, clickedEvent.target);




pure js object demo

const obj = {};
obj;
// {}
Object.prototype.toString(obj)
// '[object Object]'


